# A Putnam Integral $\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}\,dx}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)} + \sqrt{\ln(x+3)}}.$

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

This is a Putnam Problem that I have been trying to solve (on and off) for two years, but I have failed. I am in Calculus BC. This problem comes from the book "Calculus Eighth Edition by Larson, Hostetler, and Edwards". This problem is at the end of the first section of the chapter 8 exercises. Here's the problem:

Evaluate $$\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}\,dx}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)} + \sqrt{\ln(x+3)}}.$$

Please. Any help is very much appreciated. So are solutions. Thank you!

**Edit**: I like the solution given, but I was interested to see if there is any other way of doing the problem? I'm excited to see the results.

Comment: In general, when there's a symmetry (such as around $x=3$ in this problem), it's a good idea to try to exploit that symmetry.  Which is more easily said once you've seen the answer.

Comment: Yes. I had a feeling that there was an inherent symmetry, but I was doubting myself so I didn't take a serious enough look at it. Glory is achieved by the fearless and not the second guessers. I need to start taking symmetry much more seriously! Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Let
$$ \mathcal{I}=\int_{2}^{4}\dfrac{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}+\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x $$
Now, use that
$$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\overset{(1)}{=}\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)\,\mathrm{d}x $$
Then,
$$ \mathcal{I}=\int_{2}^{4}\dfrac{\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}+\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x $$
Add up these two integrals to get
$$ 2\mathcal{I}=\int_{2}^{4}\dfrac{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}+\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}+\sqrt{\ln(3+x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x $$
Thus,
$$ \mathcal{I}=1 $$

In order to prove $(1)$, write the integral using another variable, say, $t$:
$$ \int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-t)\,\mathrm{d}t $$
In the latter one, set $x=a+b-t$ and $\mathrm{d}t=-\mathrm{d}x$ and change the limits of integration to obtain
$$ \begin{aligned}
\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-t)\,\mathrm{d}t&=-\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{aligned} $$

Comment: There is an interesting (very) related article published in MATHEMATICS MAGAZINE VOL. 81, NO. 2, APRIL 2008, and entitled ''Lazy Student Integrals'' By GREGORY GALPERIN & GREGORY RONSSE.

Comment: Very Nice Solution.

Comment: I would just note the intuition on the equality (1) is you get the same area if you count the area moving left to right as you do right to left.