# Issues on solving $\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}+\sqrt{\cos(x)}}\,dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, solution-verification

$$\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}+\sqrt{\cos(x)}}\,dx$$ I was trying to solve this yesterday and did the following: divide num and den by $\sqrt{\sin x}$ $$\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\cot(x)}}\,dx$$ I did the u-sub $u=\sqrt{\cot(x)}$ such that $du=\frac{-\csc^2(x)}{2\sqrt{\cot(x)}}\,dx$ $$-2\int^0_{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\cot x}}{(1+u)\csc^2x}\,du$$ flipping the bounds and using $\csc^2x=1+\cot^2x$ $$\int^{+\infty}_0\frac{u}{(1+u)(1+u^4)}\,du$$ then did partial fractions and according to wolfram alpha the partial fractions are correct: \begin{align} 2\left[\int^{+\infty}_0 \vphantom{\int^{+\infty} \frac{\frac12}{u^4}} \right. & \frac{-\frac12}{1+u}\,du+\int^{+\infty}_0\frac{\frac12 u^3}{1+u^4}\,du \\[8pt]
& \left. {} +\int^{+\infty}_0\frac{-\frac12 u^2}{1+u^4}\,du+\int^{+\infty}_0\frac{\frac12 u}{1+u^4}\,du+\int^{+\infty}_0\frac{\frac12}{1+u^4}\,du\right]\end{align} but I want to stop here since I don't think I've committed any mistakes but somehow the first 2 integrals do diverge? And the initial integral does converge so I don't know what have I done incorrectly (if I have)

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)dx = \int_0^{\pi/2}f(\frac{\pi}2-x)dx$

Comment: $I=\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}+\sqrt{\cos(x)}}dx=\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{\sqrt{\cos(x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}+\sqrt{\cos(x)}}dx$. Thus $2I=\frac{\pi}{2}$. THis type of question has been asked many tmes. You may want to check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957510/a-putnam-integral-int-24-frac-sqrt-ln9-x-dx-sqrt-ln9-x-sqrt?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I should remark that I don't want an alternative solution, I'm asking for the verification of what I did (as I said in the post), thanks

Comment: If $\int_A (f+g)$ converges, but $\int_A f$ or $\int_A g$ does not, then $\int_A (f+g) \neq \int_A f + \int_A g$. That is your mistake.

Comment: Wait so the "splitting the integrals" was the incorrect step? Then what's the point of like doing partial fractions? I'm astonished

Comment: Integration by partial fractions would work over any finite interval.  One possible approach would be to compute the integral from $0$ to $N$ and then take the limit as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: At the point where you have the following

$$\displaystyle I = \int^{+\infty}_0\frac{u}{(1+u)(1+u^4)}\,du $$

Let $\displaystyle u \mapsto \frac{1}{u}$ then


$$\displaystyle I = \int^{+\infty}_0\frac{u^2}{(1+u)(1+u^4)}\,du $$


Adding them together then:

$$\begin{aligned} 2I & = \int^{+\infty}_0\frac{u}{1+u^4}\,du \\& = \frac{1}{2}\arctan{u^2}\bigg|_0^{\infty} = \frac{\pi}{4}.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: It can happen that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \big(f(u)+g(u)\big) \, du$ converges absolutely but $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty f(u) \, du = +\infty$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty g(u) \, du = -\infty.$ In such cases, you can sometimes find the antiderivative of the sum of two functions, and thus the integral over a bounded interval, and then find the limit as the upper end of the interval approaches $+\infty.$ But in this case there is a simpler way to find the definite integral than by finding the indefinite integral. See my answer below. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct, except for a missing factor of $2$ in the integral.  It should be $$\int^{+\infty}_0\frac{2u}{(1+u)(1+u^4)}du$$

Before splitting the integrand into partial fractions, it would be well to factor the denominator into polynomials of degree at most $2$. $$u^4+1=(u^2+1)^2-2u^2=(u^2+\sqrt2u+1)(u^2-\sqrt2u+1)$$

Then there should be no trouble computing the indefinite integral, but I did it in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%202x%2F%28%281%2Bx%29%281%2Bx%5E4%29%29%20x%20from%200%20..%20infinity).  It's easy to see that the antiderivative goes to $0$ at $\infty$ and that the value at $0$ is $-\frac\pi4$.

**EDIT**

In response to OP's comment.

The issue of convergence of the individual integrals is irrelevant.  We want to compute $$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\int^{x}_0\frac{2u}{(1+u)(1+u^4)}du$$

If we look at the indefinite integral in WolframAlpha we see the terms $\log(1+x^4)$ and $-4\log(1+x)$.  Neither of these expressions has a limit at $\infty$ but
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\log(1+x^4)-4\log(1+x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\log\frac{1+x^4}{(1+x)^4}=0$$

Comment: What about the question of convergence of those first two integrals in that last display?

Comment: oh okay thanks! I should've used the limit for the infinity part instead of vaguely "plugging" infinity, that solves everything up.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \int^{\pi/2}_0\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx \\[12pt]
= {}& \int_{\pi/2}^0 \frac{\sqrt{\cos u}}{\sqrt{\cos u} +\sqrt{\sin u}} \, (-du) \\[8pt]
& u=\frac\pi2-x, \qquad du = -dx.
\end{align}

Therefore
$$
\int^{\pi/2}_0\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx = \int^{\pi/2}_0\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx
$$
and the sum of these two is $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} 1\,dx.$